# Conditional probabilities with more than 1 vertical bar

Tags: conditional-probability

I was looking at a reference today and saw a conditional probability written with more than 1 vertical bar $P(A|B|C)$. This is the first time I've seen something like this. Is this valid syntax. Is there another way to represent this?

Comment: What reference?

Comment: @AnginaSeng. It's from some handwritten lecture notes that I have.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I feel like based on context, it seems to be $P(A|B,C)$. This was regarding a 2 player game russian roulette game with a single bullet located in 6 chambers. I saw them write P(A|B), where A is the event that the first player survives the second round given that the first player survives the first round (represented with B). C is the event that the 2nd player survives the first round. Then they wrote $P(A|B) = P(A|B|\bar{C})P(\bar{C}) + P(A|B|C)P(C)$ i.e., the total probability formula.

Comment: In Yor Revus book, if I'm not mistaken, they sometimes write $\mathbb E(X\mid Y\mid Z)$ for $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]\mid Z]$.

Comment: @Surb Is that just for expectation, or did write something for probability notation too? I feel like in my case, the person meant to write $P(X|Y \cap Z)$

Comment: @user5965026: You can adapt as follow : $$\mathbb P(X\in A\mid Y\mid Z)=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{X\in A\}}\mid Y]\mid Z]=\mathbb E[\mathbb P(X\in A\mid Y)\mid Z].$$

But in your precise case, I don't know. They should have defined it somewhere. The notation $\mathbb P(A\mid B\mid C)$ for $\mathbb P(A\mid B\cap C)$ seems a bit silly at my point of view. But it could means that. I really don't know.